# $watch function gives undefined - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am a very basic beginner in AngulerJS.

What i'm trying to do is that when a user clicks on a product, the types of that product come up, then they pick a type and the colors of that type come up. I've tried using the same system that gets the types to show but my colors keep coming up undefined.

```
<section class="colorDisplay">
  <div class="mcolor" ng-repeat="color in shoColor">
  <img ng-src="{{color.image}}"/></div>
</section>
```

**script.js**

```
$scope.prod = {"name":"Pens"};
$scope.typ = {"id":1};
$scope.$watch('prod.name',function(){
    $http.get("products/"+$scope.prod.name+".json").success(function(data){
    $scope.type = data;
    });
    $scope.$watch('typ.id',function(type){
    $scope.shoColor = type[$scope.typ.id].colors;
}); 
})
```

**JSON File**

```
{
"types":[
    {
        "name":"laser",
        "id":0,
        "image":"d-u-b/pens/laser.png",
        "colors":[
            {
                "color":"Black and Silver",
                "image":"colors/blacksilver.png",
                "prodimage":"d-u-b/pens/laser/blacksilver.png"
            },
            {
                "color":"Red",
                "image":"colors/red.png",
                "prodimage":"d-u-b/pens/laser/red.png"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"plain",
        "id":1,
        "image":"d-u-b/pens/plain.png",
        "colors":[
            {
                "color":"Yellow",
                "image":"colors/yellow.png",
                "prodimage":"d-u-b/pens/plain/yellow.png"
            },
            {
                "color":"Blue",
                "image":"colors/blue.png",
                "prodimage":"d-u-b/pens/plain/yellow.png"
            },
            {
                "color":"Cyan",
                "image":"colors/cyan.png",
                "prodimage":"d-u-b/pens/plain/cyan.png"
            },
            {
                "color":"Silver",
                "image":"colors/silver.png",
                "prodimage":"d-u-b/pens/plain/silver.png"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I'm trying to call the id number of a certain types colors, putting it into something like this: types[0].colors, where the 0 is the inserted id number.
No matter where I put the watch function or what I name it, it's either the "0" is undefined or "colors" is undefined.

What am I doing wrong this time?

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$scope.shoColor = type[$scope.typ.id].colors;
```

to

```
$scope.shoColor = $scope.type[type].colors;
```

and

```
$http.get("products/"+$scope.prod.name+".json").success(function(data){
$scope.type = data;
```

to

```
$http.get("products/"+$scope.prod.name+".json").success(function(response){
$scope.type = response.data;
```

Comment: It's still giving me "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" and whenever I click on a different type it gives me "Cannot read property 'colors' of undefined"

Comment: With all due respect Ian that line is a problem related to this case

Comment: It's still giving me "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" when I click on a product and it won't display the product types now.

Comment: then omit the second bit with the http change

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5nHA/1/) of what i think you are trying to achieve.

**note:**  - i have hard coded the `$scope.type data` in order for it to work on jsfiddle.

i have used nested ng-repeats as it follows the same code structure as the json response.

Hope it helps,

D

Comment: I think it was because I wasn't going deep enough into the json file for it to grab colors. I looked at your file and noticed that. Changing:    `$scope.shoColor = $scope.type[$scope.typ.id].colors;` to `$scope.shoColor = $scope.type.types[$scope.typ.id].colors;` It stills gives me "types is undefined" but it still works.